# How to Center ListView?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have Column but issue is if screen very small height there is error:

> BOTTOM OVERFLOWED BY 5.0 PIXELS

```
Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        CenterBoxText(),
                        SizedBox(height: 1),
                        RaisedButton(
                          child: Text(‘Example’),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
```

I have try replace `Column` with `ListView` and this stop error. But now on large screen Widget are display from top and not in center. Because `ListView` no have `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center`.

How to solve?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Having a ListView always placed at the center of the screen? Or a ListView with all its elements centered?

Comment: @Escobar Thanks for reply! I want `ListView` at center of screen

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your `Column` widget with `SingleChildScrollView` widget, It will provide the ability to scroll.
Like this :

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                       children: <Widget>[
                         CenterBoxText(),
                         SizedBox(height: 1),
                         RaisedButton(
                           child: Text(‘Example’),
                         ),
                       ],
                     ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems with the Column creating an overflow, then it is probably overflow in the vertical axis. ListView enables scrolling in the vertical axis and allows the overflow pixels to be below the viewing screen. That is why ListView works for you and Column doesn't. Since you want Column, then you just need to wrap the Column in an Expandable so the Column fits within the available space.

Here is a complete example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ColumnTest extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
                //CenterBoxText(),
                SizedBox(height: 1),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('example'),
                ),
            ],
          ),
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I cannot use `Column` because pixel overflow on small screen size

Comment: Can you update your question with the ListView code? I can provide an answer for you.

Comment: Is just replace `Column` with `ListView` and remove `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `Column` with `ListView`.

In  your `ListView` - add -    `shrinkWrap: true,` then wrap your `ListView` with `Center` widget.